# How can the resultant magnetic field magnitude at two points, which are at different distance from a current carrying wire wire, have the same value?

Tags: magnetic-fields

So I was taking a look at the H-field resulting from two parallel wires carrying the same amount of current, but in opposite directions(image below) and the resulting field seems to be opposite of what i would expect.

If we were for example to take two points on the X-axis, let's say for example the points **x<sub>1</sub>** and **x<sub>2</sub>** like I've marked on the image, the field in point **x<sub>1</sub>** is made up of the fields of the two wires (which point in the same direction, thus adding up). On the other hand, the field in point **x<sub>2</sub>** is the result of subtracting the field from the wire on the right from the field created by the wire on the left.

Now, what I do not understand is the fact that the field on the two aforementioned points can have the same magnitude (since they lie on the same field line), in spite of the fact that **x<sub>2</sub>** is way further from the left wire than **x<sub>1</sub>** is and despite the fields of the two wires having the same directions in **x<sub>1</sub>** and opposite directions in **x<sub>2</sub>**.

Thank you in advance to anyone who tries to help!

[image: field lines between parallel wires]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the lines of induction around a wire mean. They show the direction of the field. You can plot the B vector at many points. Then you can start at a point draw a curve that follows the direction of the field. You will find the curve forms a closed loop. Drawing lots of loops shows the "shape" of the field.

The spacing of the lines shows the strength of the field.

This is similar to the E field. E field lines start on a charge and spread out radially. Near the charge, field lines are closely spaced and the field is high. Far away, they are spread out and the field is weak.

You don't really get a sense of this from looking at the field around a single wire. You can draw lines where ever you want. To see it, you have to look at two nearby field lines. They stay the same distance apart. The field strength stays the same everywhere on a field line.

For two wires, you can see that closely spaced lines between the wires do spread out. This shows the field is stronger at $x_1$ than $x_2$.

Comment: So if I understood correctly in the case when the distance between two field lines stays the same, the assumption that the field strength along each one of those lines is constant, is actually correct. And in the case of the arrangment in the question above the assumption that the field strength along a field line is constant, is wrong. Is that right?

Comment: @Burner - Correct